# Select2 4.0 - Replacement for blur event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I use Select2 version 4.0.0 for select box. I need to know when it lost focus (and trigger another, custom event). Due to the [changelog](https://github.com/select2/select2/releases/tag/4.0.0) of newest Select2 release `select2-blur` event was removed. Is there any known workaround?

Comment: won't the event `select2:close` work for you. I mean when the Select2 element loses _focus_ or its _blurred_, its _closed_ right? Try it.

Comment: It won't. I understand your idea, but in my case it will not help. I need exactly _blur_ or _focus out_ replacement. Thanks for suggestion, though.

Comment: Since Select2 hides the original `<select>` element the `on` binding before applying `select2()` on the element doesn't work. And after applying `select2()` _blur_ doesn't work (I tried). If you find a workaround please share ;)